# iPhone:Add tabbarcontroller for a particular area of my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iphone app where the **First four screens are navigation based**.

From fifth screen the design changed to a **Tabbar based one**.In this tabbar based section we are able to navigate the subviews on each tab.

**How could I implement this?**

**Where do I declare the tabbar Controller-In appDelegate or in some other files?**

Answer (score 1):

You can add observer in your app-delegate class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(youMethod)        
                                                 name:@"loginSucess" 
                                               object:nil];


- (void)youMethod
{
    UINavigationController *controller = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController] autorelease];


    self.window.rootViewController = controller;    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and for the action were you want to add your tabbar you can call like this

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginSucess" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

in app delegate you declared the first 5 screens (Screen 1 to 5)
Lets say on a button of screen 5 you want to launch a tab bar
You do the following:

```
//Create the tab bar controller
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
//Create the 5 new view controllers
UIViewController *cont_1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

//Add them to array
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cont_1, cont_2, ... , nil]
[tabBar setViewControllers:arr];

//Now push the tab bar controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Tabbar controller prgrammatically and add tabbarcontroller into navigationController

```
MyFirstViewController *myFirstViewController = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] init];
MySecondViewController *mySecondViewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];

myFirstViewController.array = self.array;


NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myFirstViewController, mySecondViewController, nil];
UITabBarController *tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tab.viewControllers = array;

[array release];

UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"first title" image:nil tag:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"second title" image:nil tag:2];

myFirstViewController.tabBarItem = item1;
mySecondViewController.tabBarItem = item2;



[self.navigationController pushViewController:tab animated:YES];
```

Use this code this will be useful to you..

Answer (score 0):

i too had a similar prob in my app and finally i came up with pushing another UIViewController and adding the UITabBarController view as a subview.

when u are on your 4th screen and u navigate to the 5th screen which is also a UIViewController. and i am supposing u hv 3 tabs.

in viewDidLoad of this UIViewController

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIViewController1 *objUIViewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController1" bundle:nil];
UIViewController2 *objUIViewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController2" bundle:nil];
UIViewController3 *objUIViewController3 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController3" bundle:nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objUIViewController1, objUIViewController2, objUIViewController3, nil];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Title1"];
[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"title2"];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[UIViewController1 release];
[UIViewController2 release];
[UIViewController3 release];
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)